# While contando zero a mais

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int zeros(signed char *V, int n){
    int i = 0;
    while(!V[i] && i < n){ // Ou acabou o vetor caso seja inteiro zero
        i++;
    }

    return i;
}
   
int main(){
    int n = 0;
    char aux;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    
    signed char * X = calloc(n, sizeof(signed char));
    
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%c", &aux);
        X[i] = atoi(&aux);
    }
    printf("%d", zeros(X, n));
    return 0;
}
```

Esse código lê o tamanho do vetor `X` alocado dinamicamente com um `calloc` e retorna a quantidade de zeros à esquerda. Primeiro insere o tamanho do vetor e depois um número que é armazenado dígito a dígito em um vetor, por exemplo, esta é uma simulação do que eu queria que acontecesse

```
5
00123
2
```

Mas a função está retornando

```
5
00123
3
```

Ou seja, o `while()` dentro da função está contabilizando um '0' a mais, o `!V[i]` no `if()` é responsável por verificar se o valor `V[i]` é zero, se for zero retorna `False` e o '!' nega o `False`, retornando `True`. Alguém poderia me explicar o porquê estar sendo contabilizado um zero a mais, ou melhor, por que ele está entrando mais uma vez no `while()`? Obs: uso Linux.

Comment: Uma dúvida... Vc está na dúvida se está usando c, c++ ou c#? Pq as 3 tags?

Comment: Porque supus que quem programa em uma delas provavelmente conhece uma das outras duas...

Comment: Não é para usar um monte de tags de linguagens diferentes, é para usar somente da linguagem que está sendo usada no código da pergunta. E a sua suposição não é sempre verdade, quem conhece uma não necessariamente vai conhecer outra - e mesmo que conhecesse, não é para fazer isso, só coloque as tags que realmente têm relação com a pergunta.

Comment: Quanto às tags: suposição errada. Estude qual é o significado delas. Quanto ao programa o primeiro caractere lido (X[0]) é o ENTER que ficou no buffer após a leitura de `n`.

Comment: Douglas Supôs errado. A pergunta deve ser clara quanto ao conteúdo e informação técnica. A apresentação de informação deliberadamente equivocada enseja a edição, o fechamento ou remoção da pergunta e até os casos raros, mas existentes, de advertência, sansão punitiva e exclusão de conta.

Answer (score 0):

Além do erro referido no comentário (X[0] receber o ENTER anterior), existe um erro na chamada à função atoi.
Esta função recebe o ponteiro para aux, que é uma variável simples, quando deveria receber o ponteiro para uma string (uma string é uma sequência de caracteres terminada com o caracter cujo código é zero).
Este código aparenta funcionar bem enquanto o conteúdo da posição de memória a seguir a aux for zero.